# how to push arr2d in arr2d in javascipt

Tags: javascript, lodash

i want to prepare data to machine learning in decision tree model
and i create file csv in nodejs 
i have problem in the process of creating csv is 
explain in array :
case [1,2,100] is chose 1 and 2 answer 100 then answer  can same other array
and Now i can push array in the same case is   
Ex:

```
input= [[1,2,100],[2,3,110]]
data = [[1,2,100]]
```

then

```
data = [[1,2,100],[2,3,110],[1,2,100]]
```

with code this :

```js
input= [[1,2,100],[2,3,110]]
data = [[1,2,100]]
data.push(...input)
console.log(data)
```

but  I do not want

I am looking for best ways of doing this:

```
input= [[1,2,100],[2,3,110]]
data = [[2,3,99]]
```

the last index(is [1,2,**100**],[2,3,**110**]) can same with arr other.
Ex [2,3,110] have in data [2,3,99] ,don't can push
Ex [1,2,100] don't have in data ,can push

The end result I want is an array 2d :

```
data = [[1,2,99],[2,3,110]]
```

How do I do it the most efficient/clean way ? Thanks!

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you please clarify more?

Comment: What do you mean with 'last index'?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to insert array from `input` into `data` if the first two values in it aren't present in `data`? Also, I assume you want the array sorted by first number, then second and ultimately third?

Comment: I am editing a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

- concat the arrays,
- sort by values
- reduce the array with a map where the largets value of a group wins,
- get the values from the map
- get an array of all values as result.

```js
var data = [[2, 3, 55], [2, 4, 110], [3, 1, 110], [3, 2, 115], [3, 3, 120], [4, 1, 120]],
    input = [[1, 2, 100], [2, 3, 110]],
    result = Array.from([...data, ...input]
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2])
        .reduce((m, a) => m.set(`${a[0]}|${a[1]}`, a), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. so thanks